# How to change an image by dragging another one towards it?

Tags: javascript, image, function, draggable

So I am trying to change picture A to picture B by dragging picture B over it. I got it working with just one picture, but I want it to work with multiple.[This image kind of pictures what I want to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBNgj.jpg)

What I have so far in JS:

```js
function movePlayer1() {
    if (document.getElementById("pack")) {
        document.getElementById("spot1").src = "image/" + playerImg1;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("spot1").src = "image/" + playerImg2;
    }
}
document.querySelectorAll("img#spot1")[0].addEventListener("dragover", movePlayer1);
```

I am new to Javascript, but I have tried multiple things and couldn't figure out how to do this, so I'm hoping someone can help me with this. If I need to give any extra information, please let me know!

(When I drag "playerImg2" over document.getElementById("pack"), it still changes to "playerImg1" instead of "playerImg2".)

Thanks.

Comment: What errors are in console when you hit F12?

Comment: Failed to load resource: image/undefined the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: That means that `playerImg1` is not a valid image :)

Comment: check your path or double check `playerImg1` and `playerImg2` are valid.

Comment: But the playerImg1 is the one that works but the other one doesn't actually

Comment: When I use playerImg2 just on it's own, it works though, the problem is that when I have multiple, I don't know the correct code to make it change to either. So when I drag the playerImg2 over the changing image, it still changes to playerImg1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a **background image** for your droppable areas,
and play with the draggability of your images:

```js
const isClass = (cl, el) => el.classList.contains(cl);
const on = (typ, el, cb) => el.addEventListener(typ, cb);
let dragEl;

on("dragover",  document, (e) => e.preventDefault() );
on("dragend",   document, (e) => e.target.style.opacity = 1 );
on("dragstart", document, (e) => {
  dragEl = e.target;
  e.target.style.opacity = 0;
});
on("drop", document, (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(isClass("dropArea", e.target)) {
    dragEl.remove();
    e.target.append( dragEl );
  }
});
```

```css
.dropArea {
  display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;
  width: 57px; height: 87px; margin: 8px;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nsDs.png') no-repeat 50% 50% / cover;
}
.dropArea.small{
  width:  30px; height: 40px;
}
.dropArea img{
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropArea"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBQ1c.png" draggable="true"></div>
<div class="dropArea"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR6MI.png" draggable="true"></div>
<div class="dropArea"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSBBq.png" draggable="true"></div>
<div class="dropArea small"></div>
<div class="dropArea small"></div>
<div class="dropArea small"></div>
```